# javascript image loading issue

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, yail

Ok basically im an idiot and i dont know what im doing.. i'm a complete javascript noob. All i want is to create a canvas in which it loads an add image, mouth image, a clock image(based on the time) and a pill ON TOP of the clock. I'm using YAIL in this code but i've tried so many ways and im utterly clueless as to what im doing wrong.. Could someone please help me. The pill is also supposed to be eventually be dragged into the mouth and register this on a database.
Also i began coding in line out of prove simplicity but when i tried to change it to another file, knowing my luck, it didnt work for god knows what reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> body{ background:#ddd;}
canvas { background:#fff;
 display: block;
 margin: 10px auto; 
 box-shadow: 0 5px 15px #aaa;}</style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="yail.1.4.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="action.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<script>
var Canvas = function(canvasEl, width, height){
this.el= canvasEl;
this.el.width = width;
this.el.height = height;
this.ctx = canvasEl.getContext("2d");
}
var canvas = new Canvas(document.querySelector("#mycanvas"), 1100, 650);
drawadd();
function drawadd(){
var add = new Image();

add.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 500,-215);
};
add.src="add.png";
}


drawmouth();
function drawmouth(){
var mouth = new Image();

mouth.onload = function() {
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(this, 100,300,175,100);
};
mouth.src="mouth.png";
}

var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = currentdate.getHours();
var loader = new YAIL(done, progress, errors);

if(datetime==1||datetime==13){
loader.add("clock/clock1.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==2||datetime==14){
loader.add("clock/clock2.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==3||datetime==15){
loader.add("clock/clock3.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==4||datetime==16){
loader.add("clock/clock4.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==5||datetime==17){
loader.add("clock/clock5.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==6||datetime==18){
loader.add("clock/clock6.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==7||datetime==19){
loader.add("clock/clock7.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==8||datetime==20){
loader.add("clock/clock8.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==9||datetime==21){
loader.add("clock/clock9.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==10||datetime==22){
loader.add("clock/clock10.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==11||datetime==23){
loader.add("clock/clock11.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}
else if(datetime==0||datetime==12){
loader.add("clock/clock12.png");
loader.add("clock/pill.png");
}


loader.load();
function done(e) { 
    var imageLst = e.images;
    var urlLst = e.urls;
    }
function progress(e) { var current = e.current;
    var total = e.total;
    var image = e.img;
    var pst = current / total * 100; }

function errors(e) { var url = e.url;
    var originalErrorObject = e.error; }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

An in depth answer would be greatly appreciated because im such a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to add drawing code to the `done` handler:

```
function done(e) { 
    var imageLst = e.images;

    canvas.ctx.drawImage(imageLst[0], 500, -215);
    canvas.ctx.drawImage(imageLst[1], 500, -215);
}
```

It's a bit unclear in what position you want to draw the resulting images but you should be able to adjust the x (500) and y (-215) positions accordingly (I just copied what you had).

The other loading code in the first part seems a bit redundant as you are using a loader.

Comment: The previous ones never overlapped and it was sort of a work in progress going from on tutorial or one persons answer on stackoverflow etc. That was just the point that i got stuck on because doing it like i did for add.png and mouth.png would sometimes load the pill behind the clock etc. Just to clarify the images will always load in that order now i.e. the clock then the pill on top? also any pointers for making it drag and drop able? But this definitely worked.

Comment: @user2232418 yes, using YAIL and the `done` callback guarantees all images are loaded in the order you define with the url-array. For drag-and-drop you can also check out [easyCanvasJS](http://easycanvasjs.com/) which has built-in support for dragging images onto canvas (from desktop folder), or if you need browser-inline drag-and-drop simply [do a search here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=drag+and+drop+canvas). There has been a few Q&As on that topic recently.

Comment: much appreciated one last question, in the done function, how would i take the imageLst[1] for example as a reference to be operated on like if i wanted to to add an event listener? I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: @user2232418 ..hm, not quite sure what you mean here. You can always declare a variable outside the function (f.ex. global scope) and then set that variable with the image and from the `done` callback somehow tell that the image is loaded by f.ex setting the event listener from within that function. This way events from others parts will only handled when the image is actually loaded. A flag is also a way to go. Hope this helps.

Comment: well for example i added the line "var pill;" above the var currentdate line. then in the done function under the last draw image i added pill = imageLst[1]; and this didnt seem to work because i tried to draw pill and it didnt work